# Does a given Turing machine works in time limited by $5n$?

Tags: computability, turing-machines, undecidability, proof-techniques

There doesn't exist an algorithm which decides on the following problem:
Does a given Turing machine work in time limited by $5n$? $n$ is the length of $w$. $w$ is an input word.

The answer is:

No, because if it was  true then we would decide on problem: Does an universal machine accept a word $w$.

I don't understand why that argument works. Please explain.

Comment: What do you mean by "...Turing machine works in time..."? Works for at least $5n$ steps? Also please define what $n$ is.

Comment: @Evil The  set of Turing machines which halt in time (at most) $5n$ steps **on all inputs** is decidable, for some fixed $n$. No?

Comment: @fade2black yes, you are absolutely right, it is decidable. I have parsed the question differently, 5n not as the numbers of steps it performs, so given that I retract my comment, it does matter what $n$ denotes, thank you.

Comment: Could you please indicate the source of the question? Book, notes...?

Comment: The are proposing a reduction partner here, leaving you to come up with the reduction. Try doing so!